# Setting up and using Meld as your git difftool and mergetool on a Mac

Tags: macos, merge, diff, git-config, meld

How can I install Meld on MacOS, and then set it up as my difftool and mergetool in git?

Answer (score 52):

1. Download the latest `.dmg` package for Mac from here: [Meld for OSX](https://yousseb.github.io/meld/)
2. Set meld as your git difftool/mergetool by editing your `~/.gitconfig` and adding the following lines, as mentioned in the above link:

   ```
   [diff]
     tool = meld
   [difftool]
     prompt = false
   [difftool "meld"]
     trustExitCode = true
     cmd = open -W -a Meld --args \"$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\"
   [merge]
     tool = meld
   [mergetool]
     prompt = false
   [mergetool "meld"]
     trustExitCode = true
     cmd = open -W -a Meld --args --auto-merge \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$BASE\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\" --output=\"$PWD/$MERGED\"
   ```
3. Use the [`git difftool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) command in your repo to compare and edit files between revisions.

Comment: I get meld command not found.  How did you get meld into /usr/local/bin?

Comment: `$PWD` part was missing for me, it seems it was not needed before. Thanks!

Comment: git diftool sometimes gives you relative and sometimes absolute paths. Looks like Meld can't deal with this very well, so you need to do something like `\"$([[ "$REMOTE" == /* ]] && echo "$REMOTE" || echo "$PWD/$REMOTE")\"`

Answer (score 23):

From Mac OS High Sierra (10.13.6), Git 2.12.2

**Install Meld**

`brew tap homebrew/cask`

`brew cask install meld`

**Set Meld as Git Mergetool**

`git config --global merge.tool meld`

`git config --global  diff.guitool meld`

Comment: If you don't have brew installed, please follow directions here first: https://brew.sh/

Comment: If you're on a corporate/firewalled network, be sure to set your http & https proxies.  

`export http_proxy=<YOUR_PROXY_HOST>:<PORT>`  

`export https_proxy=<YOUR_SECURE_PROXY_HOST>:<PORT>`   

Then run the steps above.

Comment: For some reason, when I use the homebrew version of meld, meld will appear in the the dock, close, and then reopen but no meld windows will actually open; the icon will just sit in the dock doing nothing.

Comment: I have the same experience as Alexej Magura currently, and the suggested .gitconfig in other answers did not seem to work either

Comment: For the second command, I have to use `brew install --cask meld` on Apple M1

Answer (score 11):

Working solution starting from **2021**

- Operational System: Mac OS Big Sur (11.3.1)
- Git: Git 2.30.1

#### Install

```rb
brew tap homebrew/cask
```

```rb
brew install --cask meld
```

#### Setup

```rb
git config --global merge.tool meld
```

```rb
git config --global  diff.guitool meld
```

#### Usage

```rb
git mergetool # When file conflicts happen during merge
```